# Need asistance with dequeing an array

Tags: c

Ok guys. I can see the finish line with this project I am doing. I'm trying to figure out why my array spitting out NULLS when I try to return the values(i.e. dequeue) an array.I'm confident my enquue function works, and am also confident that it's taking in the values from the address the pointer refers to. this is the code I have. I purposefully didnt include my main function just because I didnt want to overload the board. But if it needs to be seen to diagnose the problem, please let me know.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// the capacity of the queue
#define CAPACITY 10

// a queue
typedef struct
{
    // the index of the first element in the queue
    int head;

    // storage for the elements in the queue
    char* strings[CAPACITY];

    // the size of the queue
    int size;
}
queue;

// declare a queue (as a global variable)
queue q;

/*
* Puts a new element into the queue into the "end" of the data structure
* so that it will be retrived after the other elements already in the
* queue.
*/
bool enqueue(char* str)
{
    int rear = 0; // back of the queue

    if (q.size==CAPACITY)         
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        rear = (rear + 1) % CAPACITY;
        q.strings[rear] = str;
        printf("%s", q.strings[rear]);

        q.size++;
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieves ("dequeues") the first element in the queue, following the
 * the "first-in, first-out" (FIFO) ordering of the data structure.
 * Reduces the size of the queue and adjusts the head to the next element.
 */
char* dequeue(void)
{
    char *charHead = NULL;   
    if (q.size)
    {
        charHead = malloc(sizeof(char)) ; 
        char *chpointer = malloc(sizeof(strArray[12]));
        q.head++;
        q.head = q.head%CAPACITY;
        charHead = q.strings[q.head];
        return charHead;        
     }       
     // Return null character if queue is empty
     return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What is `strArray`? And please try to indent better, there's no need to use `[code]`, just indent by four spaces and then indent the code properly after that.

Answer (score 1):

1. You `enqueue` surely doesn't work. How can it, when it declares `int rear = 0;`, which means that it always enqueues at the same position.
2. Your `dequeue` has two `malloc` calls that don't seem to do anything. You don't do anything with their result, and they're nothing but a memory leak.
3. You should think about the meaning of `head` and `rear`, and document it. Otherwise, there's no way of saying if `dequeue` is correct. It increments `head` first, and then takes the `q.strings[q.head]`. If `head` is the position of the last string enqueued, this is wrong - you should take the string before incrementing.
4. You never decrement `size`. This can't be right.

Comment: I think I realized my problem. Youre right, it is was enqueue. Also, I was never incrementing my array, so that it points to another subscript.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confident my enquue function works,

I cannot share your confidence since enqueue() appears to always store it's store in q.strings[1].

Comment: this is how I'm calling enqueue(and sorry for the "sloppy code"..I meant co comment some of that stuff out:
  for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        char str[12];
        sprintf(str, "%d", i);
        enqueue(strdup(str));
    }